# How do I select from an array of struct

Tags: sql, hive, complex-data-types

I'm using HIVE for Hadoop. I want to select the price value from the price field in a struct. But the struct is part of an array of struct.

```
uid     string
timestamp       int
eventdate       string
products    array<struct
    <internalId:int,
    category:int,
    alternateId:string,
    price:double,
    quantity:int,
    externalId:string>>
```

I will be querying using an exectued .HQL file, not through the terminal window.

(i.e. hive -f blah.hql > blah.txt)

How do I select the price out of the product array of struct?

-- don't know which of these, if any work. getting weird or null output.

```
Select  
  table.products.price,  
  table.products[0].price,  
  table.products['price']
from table
```

Comment: I guess this is just strange database setup on part of out cluster team. Instead of just making it a struct column, they made it an array. Yet, there is only one thing in the array for any given row - a struct. So that struct is element 0, and then I can ask for its associated field values. So products[0] is the onle array element, and products[0].price would get me the price. Can't believe that plagued me for hours!

Answer (score 2):

Answer

produts[0].price

Since the struct is the ONLY element in the array, for a given row in the table.
While this can allow for future elements in the products array, it would have nice  to make that column JUST a struct.